# Draw according to touch speed

Tags: ios, opengl-es

can anybody tell me how to draw free hand in opengl but according to touch speed. I have seen apple GLPaint and use it.But i want to implement draw according to touch speed like 
**NoteShelf app**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what NoteShelf app is, but I think what you want is probably something similar to the Dynadraw code that Paul Haeberli made in 1989.  Basically, you want to create a small physics engine to keep track of a mass-spring system that is attached to the touch-point.  Then, you can use the mass' velocity to control drawing parameters like pen width, color, etc.

Some references:

- The original code is here:  http://www.graficaobscura.com/dyna/index.html
- Processing implementation: http://processing.org/exhibition/works/dynadraw/
- Javascript: http://www.rogerandwendy.com/roger/dynadraw/index.html
- Some android code that I worked on for a while: https://bitbucket.org/rallen/android_dynadraw/overview

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your support.I need exactly what you have said.But if I get some reference related to iOS then it will be more helpful for me.

Comment: Can you tell me that computation part for calculating line width. I will convert that in iOS code

Comment: In the Processing code http://processing.org/exhibition/works/dynadraw/dynadraw.pde, look for strokeWeight(th);  In the javascript http://www.rogerandwendy.com/roger/dynadraw/dynadraw.js look for how delx & dely are calculated in draw().

I don't know iOS, so I can't really tell you more.  The android code is OpenGL ES if you want to try to dig into that--but it is much more complex.

Comment: I would like to try android code.I am much familier to OpenGL rather than Javascript.

Comment: Okay.  Check out the code revision taggged "dynadraw" for the basic implementation code.  Probably simplest to follow.  Later checkins add texturing and more complexity.  Something to think about is how you manage the list of vertices that you create with your strokes.